# How can I add duplicate sku for product by using size as option and their values

Tags: api, laravel-5, bigcommerce

Here is my code

```
$fields = array("sku" => "TestM-F", "options" => ["product_option_id" => 330,"option_value_id" => 255 ]);
$isCreated = $this->store->createSku($fields);
$error = $this->store->getLastError();
print_r($error);
print_r($isCreated);
```

I getting error like this

```
[status] => 404
[message] => The requested resource was not found.
```

product_option_id & option_value_id already present in table.
TestM sku is already exist but I want to create another sku with new name like TestM-F and by using same product_option_id & option_value_id. (duplicate).

Comment: Can you show the `createSku()` function? If you are creating a SKU, it needs to be in reference to a product (via the product ID). See: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#create-a-product-sku

Comment: public static function createSku($object)
    {
        return self::createResource('/product/skus', $object);
    }

Comment: thanks buddy.. you are right..

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use

```
 return Client::createResource('/products/' . $this->product_id . '/skus', $this->getCreateFields());
```